# Calculate Growth Rate Using PHP and Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to calculate the compound annual growth rate (CAGR) of a few products for various time periods.  I have a MySQL database that looks like this:

```
product, asof, sales
abc, 2013-06-30, 36000000
abc, 2013-12-31, 48000000
abc, 2014-01-31, 51000000
abc, 2014-02-28, 56000000
xyz, 2013-06-30, 26000000
xyz, 2013-12-31, 33000000
xyz, 2014-01-31, 33000000
xyz, 2014-02-28, 36000000
```

I've figured out the function of CAGR should look like this:

```
// EV = Ending Value
// BV = Beginning Value

function cagr($EV, $BV, $Period ) {
    $cagr = pow(($EV/$BV),(1/$Period)) - 1;
    return $cagr;
}
```

Any help or direction would be much appreciated!  Thanks!

**EDIT :**

My end goal is to create a table that contains a 3 Month, 1 Year, and 3 Year compound annual growth rate for each product.  So more specifically I need help on what MySQL queries are needed and how to structure the PHP in order to populate the table.

**EDIT 2 :**

So I've got it figured out how to get the CAGR's based on @Barmar help.  What I can't figure out is how to use PHP to get this into a table format.

Is the best way to get month end dates for various time periods using strtotime like below?

```
$lastdate = "2014-04-30";
$month3 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last day 3 months ago', strtotime($lastdate)));
$month6 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last day 6 months ago', strtotime($lastdate)));
$year1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last day of months 1 year ago', strtotime($lastdate)));
$year3 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last day 36 months ago', strtotime($lastdate)));
$year5 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last day 60 months ago', strtotime($lastdate)));
```

I've been using a function to pass in the dates into the MySQL query that @Barmar described below.

```
function queryproduct ($db, $end_date, $begin_date) {

    $q_product = "SELECT r.product, POWER(s1.sales/s2.sales, 1/(datediff(end_date, begin_date)/365)) - 1 AS cagr
                FROM (
                    SELECT product, MAX(asof) AS end_date, MIN(asof) AS begin_date
                    FROM test
                                WHERE asof BETWEEN '$begin_date' AND '$end_date'
                    GROUP BY product
                    -- Prevent divide by 0 if we don't have a range
                    HAVING end_date != begin_date) AS r
                JOIN test AS s1 ON s1.product = r.product AND s1.asof = end_date
                JOIN test AS s2 ON s2.product = r.product AND s2.asof = begin_date;";

    $q_result = mysqli_query($db, $q_product);

    return $q_result;
}
```

Comment: you seem to have worked it out, i don't see the question?

Comment: $Period is going to be the DATEDIFF() between each row for a given product are you looking for an average? What is EV/BV?

Comment: @JasonSec Presumably EV = End Value, BV = Beginning Value

Comment: @Dagon I've updated post to clarify my questions.

Comment: @JasonSec, Barmar is correct in his definitions of EV & BV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT r.product, POWER(s1.sales/s2.sales, 1/(datediff(end_date, begin_date)/365)) - 1 AS cagr
FROM (
    SELECT product, MAX(asof) AS end_date, MIN(asof) AS begin_date
    FROM sales
    WHERE asof BETWEEN :range_start AND :range_end
    GROUP BY product
    -- Prevent divide by 0 if we don't have a range
    HAVING end_date != begin_date) AS r
JOIN sales AS s1 ON s1.product = r.product AND s1.asof = end_date
JOIN sales AS s2 ON s2.product = r.product AND s2.asof = begin_date
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0cf0c/5)

UPDATE:

You can get multiple periods with:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT r1y.product product, end_date,
       begin1y, POWER(s_end.sales/s_1y.sales, 1/(datediff(r1y.end_date, begin1y)/365)) - 1 AS cagr_1y,
       begin3y, POWER(s_end.sales/s_3y.sales, 1/(datediff(r1y.end_date, begin3y)/365)) - 1 AS cagr_3y,
       begin5y, POWER(s_end.sales/s_5y.sales, 1/(datediff(r1y.end_date, begin5y)/365)) - 1 AS cagr_5y
FROM (
    SELECT product, MAX(asof) AS end_date, MIN(asof) AS begin1y
    FROM sales
    WHERE asof > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
    GROUP BY product
    -- Prevent divide by 0 if we don't have a range
    HAVING end_date != begin1y) AS r1y
JOIN (
    SELECT product, MIN(asof) AS begin3y
    FROM sales
    WHERE asof > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 YEAR)
    GROUP BY product) AS r3y
ON r1y.product = r3y.product
JOIN (
    SELECT product, MIN(asof) AS begin5y
    FROM sales
    WHERE asof > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 YEAR)
    GROUP BY product) AS r5y
ON r1y.product = r5y.product
JOIN sales AS s_end ON s_end.product = r1y.product AND s_end.asof = r1y.end_date
JOIN sales AS s_1y ON s_1y.product = r1y.product AND s_1y.asof = begin1y
JOIN sales AS s_3y ON s_3y.product = r1y.product AND s_3y.asof = begin3y
JOIN sales AS s_5y ON s_5y.product = r1y.product AND s_5y.asof = begin5y
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0cf0c/45)

Comment: Thanks @Barmar for your help!  That appears to be working great at determining the product growth from inception to end date. How would I modify the query to be able to plug in varying begin_date & end_date's, as I'm seeking to be able to show the CAGR for varying lengths of time (1 year, 3 year, etc).

Comment: I've updated the the query to show how to restrict it to a particular date range.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar, that's a better solution than I was using (I was setting mysql variables for the dates).  Any idea on how to tackle putting it all into a table?

Comment: How is this different from any other query when displaying it in a table? You just surround the values with `<td>` and `</td>`.

Comment: I'm curious as to how to efficiently use the query you suggested to populate a table that looks has the following columns: product, 1 year CAGR, 3 Year CAGR, 5 Year CAGR

Comment: I've added a version of the query that calculates multiple years of CAGR

Comment: Thank you @Barman for your patience.  I fixed the typo from INTERAL to INTERVAL and I am getting the following error: Unknown column 'begin_date' in 'having clause'

Comment: begin_date needs to change to begin1y, begin3y, and begin5y in the various clauses.

Comment: I've fixed the begin_date clauses.  Then got had the same issue with end_date, so I added `MAX(asof) AS end_date,` to each join and solved that.  Now I'm having issue with `Unknown column 'r.product' in 'field list':`.  You're a saint for putting up with me, much appreciated.

Comment: r is now r1y, r3y, r5y

Comment: I thought I had it working but I'm not sure why I'm getting multiple rows of abc & xyz? http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0cf0c/29/0

Comment: I was missing join conditions on the subqueries. Note that all three CAGRs are the same in the fiddle because you only have 1 year of data.